# How do I create a write FIFO in Python that will output one line and then wait for the next read without closing?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing a simple python script that will read the sensors from the Raspberry Pi Sense Hat and then make them available from the filesystem.

For example the information `<TEMPERATURE>:<HUMIDITY>:<PRESSURE>` will be returned when something reads from `/temp/sense`.

I have got as far as the following:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import os

# Create a PIPE from which the readings can be read
path = "/tmp/sense"
os.mkfifo(path)

# Initialise the Sense Hat
sense = SenseHat()

with open(path, "w") as pipe:
   while True:
      sense.clear()

      temp = sense.get_temperature()
      sense.clear()
      humidity = sense.get_humidity()
      sense.clear()
      pressure = sense.get_pressure()

      # Output the information
      output = "%.3f:%.3f:%.3f" % (temp, humidity, pressure)

      pipe.write(output)
      pipe.flush()

fifo.close()
```

However this continously outputs data on the same read when using `cat /tmp/sense`, which is from the `pipe.flush()`, e.g.:

```
30.88:41:101130.77:41:101130.77:41:101130.85:41:101130.77:41:101130.81:41:101130.81:41:101130.74:40:101130.77:41:101130.77:41:101130.83:42:101130.76:41:101130.70:41:1011
```

I could close the FIFO, delete the file, recreate it and then wait on each loop but that seems wrong in that something could read from the FIFO when it is not there and heavy handed. I am *sure* there must be a better way but I have not been able to find what it is.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for this, but I do not think this solves my issue. I forgot to say in my post (now corrected) that I am reading the FIFO using `cat /tmp/sense`. I want to receive just one string each time I read it. I did try and use the `truncate()` method on the writer which produced an error message. I then looked at the dupe and it seemed it was for the reader.

Comment: No, `truncate()` should be done by the writer, not the reader. But I hadn't considered the possibility that FIFOs can't be truncated. I thought they worked like regular files. My bad.

Comment: Is it crucial that the programs reading the file receive all the sensor inputs or are they allowed to skip some values every once in a while? you can for example overwrite instead of appending to the file and the programs would continously read from it once per whatever time period. You can also try to average a second of inputs for example and the reading programs would poll the file every half second so that none get missed.

Comment: @Rawing Yeah I get an `Illegal Seek` error on the `truncate()` call.

Comment: The problem is that `cat` will attempt to consume the entire pipe.  You can read just one line with `read`.

Comment: @user2464424 Reading programs can skip if they need, at least in my implementation. I can see how can overwrite would prevent the continuous output, but I would not get just one read from `cat /tmp/sense` as it does not send an EOF to cause `cat` to stop.

Comment: Are you expecting the writes to block until the data is read?  If so, realize that those blocks aren't going to happen until the pipe buffer is full, and if you are reading only one line every second or so your reads are going to be many 10s (or hundreds) of seconds behind.

Comment: There is no "send an EOF".  That is equivalent to closing the pipe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you, I will look at using `read`. Actually this is all part of a test I am building. Ultimately I want to read one line in a Go application, so using shell commands may not be the best way to test.

Comment: you don't need `fifo.close()` because the `with` context manager does that automatically.